# Scan detection Tool better than Snort Portscan Preprocessor

Tags: ids, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, detection, scan

I am working on detection of Scanning activities of Bots/Worms.
I have found that **Snort Portscan Preprocessor** detects Scan activities.
I have tweaked Snort Portscan Preprocessor to detect different types of Scanning activities.

However, I was curious to know whether a better independent scan detection tool (not an IDS like Suricata or Bro) exists and if it exists, what are the reasons is it better than Snort Portscan Preprocessor or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into Scanlogd
http://www.openwall.com/scanlogd/

Also look into psad (Port Scan Attack detector)
http://cipherdyne.org/psad/

I havent tried using either of them. Though I am not sure how much better than Snort these will be, I am sure these allow for much higher degree of customization, which may help.

Comment: Snort  allows lots of tunning,like setting different sensing modes,thresholds,Time windows,etc. .In similar way can you elaborate on "higher degree of customization" ?